# Angular 6 - HTTP response / variable tampering

Tags: javascript, angular, security

I developed an application using the MEAN stack, where a user can signup and login. When a user returns to the application after some time, I can recognize it using Express Session, but I want him to confirm its identity by typing the password (or a PIN) before giving access to the application.

So I make an HTTP call to an API (passing the password or pin) that will either return `true` or `false` to allow access to that page.

- Is it possible that someone intercepts the HTTP call (e.g. via DevTools), intercept the returned value and edit it, effectively bypassing the security check?
- Or even intercept the *router* variable and force a navigation to a specific page (not available otherwise)?
- Does Angular have in-built securities to prevent this, or do I have to implement it myself (in this case, what is the best practice)?

Thank you so much!

**EDIT:** As @bsheps pointed out, implementing AuthGuard solved the second point, about manually modifying routes to access reserved pages.
I still have to find an answer about the first point. Even when calling an HTTPS endpoint, can someone debug the code and the network requests to edit the response received from the server?

Comment: PS: Do you mind explaining the downvotes?

Comment: I don't know why people down vote and don't justify. Brining you back to 0. Valid question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- About HTTP security:

HTTP is written in plaintext and not secure. If someone intercepts your communication (Man in the middle attack), they can read your password/pin in plaintext. Additionally, they could also edit it since it is plaintext. For this reason passwords should be sent via HTTPS.

- About angular router security:

It is possible to manipulate the routes in the URL. To combat this, you can setup an authGuard for your application that will verify the login before directing to specific pages.

Here is a straight forward example to get you started: 
https://alligator.io/angular/route-guards/

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your response!! Yesterday I searched some more and bumped into the Angular authGuard and can confirm it works flawlessy!
About the HTTP security I should have been more precise, I'm indeed calling an HTTPS endpoint, but will someone still be able to edit the RESPONSE dat  by debugging the code from the Developer Tools and editing the returned values?

Comment: I suppose in theory, a user could edit the code with developer tools. The most common technique to eliminate this concern is to keep all sensitive data server side and require a server call. Why? 2 main reasons: first - the server calls are handled over HTTPS (end to end encrypted). Second - assuming your server is properly setup, the server call would verify the user before responding with the sensitive data. So even if the user is able modify a variable and access a 'restricted' area of the site, they would not have access to sensitive data because the sensitive data is stored server side.

Comment: You're correct, and for the CRUD operations I already validate every request on the server side. I guess I will just make sure that every page that contains sensitive data will properly authenticate on the server so that someone can even tamper the responses, but will eventually see just an empty page. Thank you so much for your help!